# Good methods for density plots of non-negative variables in R?

Tags: r, density-function, gamma-distribution, kernel-smoothing

```
plot(density(rexp(100))
```

Obviously all density to the left of zero represents bias.

I'm looking to summarize some data for non-statisticians, and I want to avoid questions about why non-negative data has density to the left of zero.  The plots are for randomization checking; I want to show the distributions of variables by treatment and control groups. The distributions are often exponential-ish.  Histograms are tricky for various reasons.

A quick google search gives me work by statisticians on non-negative kernels, e.g.:  [this](http://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/052_3_0471.pdf).

But has any of it been implemented in R?  Of implemented methods, are any of them "best" in some way for descriptive statistics?

EDIT:  even if the `from` command can solve my current problem, it'd be nice to know whether anyone has implemented kernels based on literature on non-negative density estimation

Comment: Not what you are asking, but I wouldn't apply kernel density estimation to something that should be exponential, especially for presentation to non-statistical audiences. I would use a quantile-quantile plot and explain that the plot should be straight if the distribution were exponential.

Comment: I'm presenting randomization checks, and I want to show the distributions of variables by treatment and control groups.  I don't have any priors on what the distributions should look like, though they often happen to be exponential-ish.  Before you ask, this is better than simply presenting means, variances, and tstats, because of outliers on the tails over-affecting means.

Comment: I see. Your initial example of an exponential did concentrate my mind. Perhaps revise your question because this comment does make much clearer what you want.

Comment: `plot(density(rexp(100), from=0))` ?

Comment: One thing that I have sometimes done fairly successfully is to get a kde on the logs, and then transform the density estimate (not forgetting the Jacobian). Another possibility would be to use a log-spline density estimate set up so it knows about the bound.

Comment: What do you do about zero values?  And I learned about jacobians from a particularly bad teacher...  Your comment might be an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I estimate the density of a zero-inflated parameter in R?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6588/how-can-i-estimate-the-density-of-a-zero-inflated-parameter-in-r)

Comment: I discussed the transformation method mentioned by @Glen_b in http://www.stata-journal.com/sjpdf.html?articlenum=gr0003 (see pp.76-78). Zeros might be accommodated by using log(x + 1) rather than log and modifying the Jacobian.

Comment: @NickCox +1 On the other hand if there are a non-trivial proportion of exact zeros, density estimation probably isn't what you want.

Comment: @Glen_b I agree. See my early comment about preferring quantile plots here myself, but I am bending over backwards to accommodate the question.

Answer (score 29):

An alternative is the approach of Kooperberg and colleagues, based on estimating the density using splines to approximate the log-density of the data. I'll show an example using the data from @whuber's answer, which will allow for a comparison of approaches.

```
set.seed(17)
x <- rexp(1000)
```

You'll need the **logspline** package installed for this; install it if it is not:

```
install.packages("logspline")
```

Load the package and estimate the density using the `logspline()` function:

```
require("logspline")
m <- logspline(x)
```

In the following, I assume that the object `d` from @whuber's answer is present in the workspace.

```
plot(d, type="n", main="Default, truncated, and logspline densities", 
     xlim=c(-1, 5), ylim = c(0, 1))
polygon(density(x, kernel="gaussian", bw=h), col="#6060ff80", border=NA)
polygon(d, col="#ff606080", border=NA)
plot(m, add = TRUE, col = "red", lwd = 3, xlim = c(-0.001, max(x)))
curve(exp(-x), from=0, to=max(x), lty=2, add=TRUE)
rug(x, side = 3)
```

The resulting plot is shown below, with the logspline density shown by the red line

[image: Default, truncated, and logspline densities]

Additionally, the support for the density can be specified via arguments `lbound` and `ubound`. If we wish to assume that the density is 0 to the left of 0 and there is a discontinuity at 0, we could use `lbound = 0` in the call to `logspline()`, for example

```
m2 <- logspline(x, lbound = 0)
```

Yielding the following density estimate (shown here with the original `m` logspline fit as the previous figure was already getting busy).

```
plot.new()
plot.window(xlim = c(-1, max(x)), ylim = c(0, 1.2))
title(main = "Logspline densities with & without a lower bound",
      ylab = "Density", xlab = "x")
plot(m,  col = "red",  xlim = c(0, max(x)), lwd = 3, add = TRUE)
plot(m2, col = "blue", xlim = c(0, max(x)), lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
curve(exp(-x), from=0, to=max(x), lty=2, add=TRUE)
rug(x, side = 3)
axis(1)
axis(2)
box()
```

The resulting plot is shown below

[image: Comparison of logspline density estimates with and without a lower bound on the support]

In this case, exploiting knowledge of `x` results in a density estimate that doesn't tend to 0 at $x = 0$, but is similar to the standard logspline fit elsewhere over `x`

Comment: +1 I like this idea but am surprised it works *so* well with the example data (from an exponential distribution). Do you have some intuition as to why that is? In some sense it does *great* near $0$ but it is missing the "lump" of values near $1$ in the actual data, so I wonder whether there's not some kind of trade-off between good accuracy at low values and low accuracy (or, equivalently, large bandwidths) at high values.

Comment: @whuber Good question. I only came across this approach recently myself. I suspect a good question to ask here is, as the truncated and logspline methods are just estimates of the true density, are the differences in fit significant, statistically? I'm not sure exactly why it does so well at zero, though. I'd appreciate knowing why too.

Comment: @GavinSimpson, Thanks for this nice answer. Can you reproduce the last plot with the lastest version of `logspline`? For me, the density of both, the bounded and the unbounded version go to zero at `x = 0`.

Answer (score 27):

One solution, borrowed from approaches to edge-weighting of spatial statistics, is to truncate the density on the left at zero but to up-weight the data that are closest to zero.  The idea is that each value $x$ is "spread" into a kernel of unit total area centered at $x$; any part of the kernel that would spill over into negative territory is removed and the kernel is renormalized to unit area.

For instance, with a Gaussian kernel $K_h(y,x) = \exp(-\frac{1}{2}((y-x)/h)^2) / \sqrt{2\pi}$, the renormalization weight is

$$w(x) = 1 / \int_0^\infty K(y,x) dy = \frac{1}{1 - \Phi_{x, h}(0)}$$

where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution function of a Normal variate of mean $x$ and standard deviation $h$.  Comparable formulas are available for other kernels.

This is simpler--and much faster in computation--than trying to narrow the bandwidths near $0$.  It is difficult to prescribe exactly how the bandwidths should be changed near $0$, anyway.  Nevertheless, this method is also *ad hoc*: there will still be some bias near $0$.  It appears to work better than the default density estimate.  Here is a comparison using a largish dataset:

[image: Figure]

The blue shows the default density while the red shows the density adjusted for the edge at $0$.  The true underlying distribution is traced as a dotted line for reference.

---

#### R code

The `density` function in `R` will complain that the sum of weights is not unity, because it wants the integral over all real numbers to be unity, whereas this approach makes the integral over positive numbers equal to unity.  As a check, the latter integral is estimated as a Riemann sum.

```r
set.seed(17)
x <- rexp(1000)
#
# Compute a bandwidth.
#
h <- density(x, kernel="gaussian")$bw # $
#
# Compute edge weights.
#
w <- 1 / pnorm(0, mean=x, sd=h, lower.tail=FALSE)
#
# The truncated weighted density is what we want.
#
d <- density(x, bw=h, kernel="gaussian", weights=w / length(x))
d$y[d$x < 0] <- 0
#
# Check: the integral ought to be close to 1:
#
sum(d$y * diff(d$x)[1])
#
# Plot the two density estimates.
#
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(d, type="n", main="Default and truncated densities", xlim=c(-1, 5))
polygon(density(x, kernel="gaussian", bw=h), col="#6060ff80", border=NA)
polygon(d, col="#ff606080", border=NA)
curve(exp(-x), from=0, to=max(x), lty=2, add=TRUE)
```

Comment: Would this be immediately applicable to multivariate KDE (2D specifically). My gut feeling says yes. If so, do you have a reference that I can point to when I'm writing the methods section of a manuscript?

Comment: @EA304GT Yes, it is applicable; and yes, I recall using it for some grid-based analyses in spatial stats.

Answer (score 4):

To compare distributions by groups (which you say is the goal in one of your comments) why not something simpler? Parallel box plots work nicely if N is large; parallel strip plots work if N is small (and both show outliers well, which you say is a problem in your data).

Comment: Yeah, thanks, that works.  But I like density plots.  They show more about the data than boxplots do.  I guess I am kind of surprised that nothing seems to have been already implemented.  Maybe I'll implement one of these things myself one day.  People would probably find it useful.

Comment: I like density plots, too; but you have to consider your audience.

Comment: Have to agree with @PeterFlom on this one.  Don't get too complicated if your audience isn't statistically knowledgeable.  You could also do comparative/parallel box-plots with an overlay of butterfly plots on top.  That way the box-plot summary is visible as well as all the data.

Comment: The suggestion that different people comprehend aggregated plots differently is certainly correct. Despite understanding what a density plot is (and understanding that it is not a probability) I have no understanding of what a "parallel boxplot" might be. It suggests a parallel coordinates plot but I suspect that is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

As Stéphane comments you can use `from = 0` and, additionally, you can represent your values under the density curve with `rug (x)`

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but `from=0` looks as if it just suppresses plotting for values below 0; it doesn't correct the calculation for the fact that some of the distribution has been smeared below 0.

Comment: That is correct.  Using the `from` command yields a plot that looks like it has the peak just right of zero.  But if you look at histograms with continually smaller bins, a lot of data will show the peak AT zero.  The `from` is just a graphical trick.

Comment: @NickCox I'm not sure but I don't think `from=0` suppresses anything. It just starts the "grid" at zero.

Comment: The difference is whether the estimated density is non-zero for negative values, not whether or not it is plotted. Researchers may decide not to worry about this if all they want is a visualization.

Comment: @NickCox The command `density(rexp(100), from=0)` has nothing to do with the graphic

Comment: @Stéphane Laurent Indeed; `plot()` is what defines the graphic. But my question (poorly expressed; I am not a routine R user) remains about precisely what is being calculated.

Comment: @NickCox I don't know. I don't really "trust" density estimation :) BTW [five years ago](http://forums.cirad.fr/logiciel-R/viewtopic.php?t=1084) I encountered the same trouble with the peak at $0$.

Comment: @Nick Even for "just" a visualization the estimation method is still worth worrying about. The default approach for most density algorithms is to produce an asymptotically unbiased estimate. To the extent to which some of the estimated density is negative (and forcibly not plotted), that reflects the removal of some of the density from the plot itself--most of which was taken from the smallest values. That creates a negative, varying bias in the KDE in the range roughly from $0$ up to two or three times the bandwidth.