# strange density plot of p-value

Tags: r, density-function, kernel-smoothing

I computed the T-score and P-value using `t.test()` for my data, and finally I've plotted the density of my p-value and I've got strange plot. I don't know, why I see peak around 0, which it's density is bigger than 1 ? 
can anybody help me with the interpretation of this plot ? I used the `plot(density(mymatrix))`
[image]

Comment: @gung, thanks. how can I avoid this problem ? for the density(), one of the kernels should be used ?

Comment: I don't see a problem. This is just how it works. You just have to understand these facts when you view / interpret this plot.

Comment: it would also make things a little less confusing to use `plot(density(mymatrix,from=0,to=1))`, i.e. set the limits to [0,1]

Comment: @Ben That's right, but it would create a biased plot: what is shown between 0 and 1 would integrate to less than unity.  See http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/65866/919 for a discussion and some solutions.