# Weighted density estimation of exponentially distributed RV

Tags: exponential-distribution, kernel-smoothing

I am trying to get a weighted density estimation of some data. Unfortunately, the data is approximately exponentially distributed after the weight transform, which gives a false sense of positive density in $\mathbb{R}^-$ and a non-existing maximum in the vicinity of the origin, when using standard KDE methods.

I found this very nice [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/71291) using `logsplines` for the density estimation of an exponentially distributed RV.
The result is impressive. Unfortunately, applying this to weighted density estimation does not seem to be straight forward.

Does `logsplines` support weighted density estimation in some form? Different approaches also warmly welcomed.

Comment: I don't think the logspline function in the logspline package has weights.

Comment: @Glen_b, yes, seems so, unfortunately

Comment: I am just wondering why you would even have to use a density estimator for an exponential distribution.