# Does this graph follow a exponential distribution or a log-normal?

Tags: distributions, exponential-distribution, lognormal-distribution

[image]

command for the graph:

```
hist(c1,freq=FALSE)
lines(density(c1,adjust=2),col="darkblue",lwd=2)
```

I generated this sequence in R:

```
set.seed(106)
lambda1<-1/98
c1<-rexp(n=1000, rate=lambda1)
```

and did a `z.test` with a significance value of 5%:

```
z.test(c1,mu=98, alternative = "two.sided", sigma.x = sd(c1), conf.level = 0.95)
```

this is the output:

data:  c1

```
z = 0.51946, p-value = 0.6034
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 98
95 percent confidence interval:
  93.43883 105.85080
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 99.64482
```

What I need to find out is if indeed the values follow a exponential distribution but I'm not sure.

Comment: A z-test doesn't tell whether data follow any particular distribution.  Use goodness-of-fit tests, such as chi-squared or Kolmogorov-Smirnov.

Comment: It's useful to keep in mind that even a goodness of fit test doesn't actually tell you whether data follow a particular distribution; they sometimes tell you that the data are not consistent with some distribution but failure to reject doesn't mean that distributional model is what the data were actually drawn from. In general data will be consistent with an infinite number of distributions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `c1` as a sample from an exponentially distributed population (in the line `c1<-rexp(n=1000, rate=lambda1)`), so that population must indeed be exponentially distributed.

(A sample itself can't be exponentially distributed; the only distribution a sample can be said to have is its empirical distribution, which must be discrete.)

Comment: But the graph does not look like an exponential, looks more like a log normal

Comment: @Joaoricardo Edit your question to include the command you used to draw the plot.

Comment: I included teh code for the graph

Comment: (+1) It looks mighty exponential to me.  The *density estimate* you computed, on the other hand, is bogus because it doesn't understand that $0$ is a left limit.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65866 for what to do about it.  (Gavin Simpson posted a nice solution.)

Comment: @Joaoricardo I agree with whuber; it seems that the problem is that the sort of kernel density estimate in question is inappropriate for this case.

Comment: I'm really new to R so what would the appropriate one be?

Comment: Do follow the link previously given by @whuber, as it is detailed and informative.

Comment: the issue is solved, I used:                   hist(c1, prob = TRUE, col = "grey")
curve(dexp(x, rate = lambda1), col = 2, lwd = 2, add = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

I've got a dataset with similar data "waiting time in seconds", which belongs to an exponential distribution according to graphs. I have tried normal, lognormal as well, but it fits best an exponential distribution.

```
    library(gsheet)
    patience.data<-gsheet2tbl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YIKOiA_xsg1ClJSYy0oZ0XYIxQzZfOqCEwolUeob_AU/edit?usp=sharing')

    wtime<-patience.data$sec
    hist(wtime,freq=FALSE)
    lines(density(wtime),col="red",lwd=2)
    #compare it with a theoretical normal distribution curve
    curve(dnorm(x,mean=mean(wtime),sd=sd(wtime)),
    add=TRUE, col="blue", lwd=2)
    legend("topright",col=c("blue","red"),legend =c("estimated normal density curve","kernel density curve"),lwd=2, bty = "n")
```

[image]

Let's fit data to an exponential distribution to the data and check it graphically

```
    require(fitdistrplus)
    fit.exp <- fitdist(wtime, "exp")
    plot(fit.exp)
```

[image]

The second and third graph look convincing

Let's fit now the histogram, density curve and exponential curve together

```
    fit.exp#get the estimated rate: 0.03482814
    hist(wtime,probability = TRUE)
    lines(density(wtime),col="red",lwd=2)
    curve(dexp(x, rate = 0.034828136), col = 3, lty = 2,lwd=2,
  add=TRUE)
    legend("topright",col=c("green","red"),
    legend =c("estimated exponential density",
             "kernel density"),
    lwd=2, bty = "n")
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid your data don't behave even *remotely* like they are drawn independently from an exponential distribution.  The histogram obscures the large spike at zero (over a quarter of the data are zeros), which provides very strong evidence against that exponential hypothesis.  This problem is very clear in the P-P plot.

Comment: I see, I was nearly convinced they followed an exponential distribution. Data aren't normal, neither log normal, which are the other options? Sorry if I am adding more confusion to this post, non intended.

Comment: Sometimes you don't need to fit a distribution at all.  If you do, an attractive option in this case would be a "zero-inflated" distribution or (more generally) a mixture of simple distributions.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's a very good point, no need to get obsessed about fitting a distribution. Zero inflated distributions look challenging though.