# Can kernel density estimation be used to estimate a radial probability density?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I am trying to estimate the PDF of the radius of points distributed in a 2D plane.  The points are distributed like this:

[image]

I can produce a histogram of the radius data which looks like this:

[image: Histogram]

I want to use kernel density estimation to produce a better result for the radial PDF and then get the value of the derivative of the PDF at $r=0$, but I immediately run into the problem that KDE will produce non-zero probability density for negative values of the radius.  Is there a simple way to use KDE for this application?  Maybe with an adaptive kernel?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One set of solutions is available at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65866.  However, the special nature of your problem provides other solutions, such as estimating the density of $r$ from (any) density estimate of $(x,y).$  Because the latter approach will produce no density for negative numbers, why not just use that?  BTW, the physical meaning of $r$ is doubtful, because it will change depending on the units of position and momentum you use.