# downsampling a kde / combining kde and histogram

Tags: sampling, kernel-smoothing, histogram, numerics

I'm calculating a KDE of one parameter (`y`, particle density) in bins of another parameter (`x`, distance from the origin).  At small `x` I have poorly sampled data (10s to 1000s of points per x-bin) while at large `x` values it is *very* well sampled (millions of points per x-bin).  At small radii, using a KDE seems very important/effective, while at large radii the result is effectively identical to a histogram, but it extremely slow to compute (at least using `scipy` in `python`) *[1].  Ultimately I don't need the KDE *per se*, I just need the smoothed/sampled PDF it produces (i.e. on a regular grid).

It seems like a hybrid approach would be possible in which the KDE is used when the sampling is sparse, but I revert to simple binning when it is very well sampled.  Is there a standard procedure for hybridizing these approaches?  Or are there techniques for adaptively choosing the bandwidth such that I can use a kernel with finite support that shrinks as the sampling becomes more dense?

*[1] Ultimately, I assume this is because I'm using Gaussian kernels with infinite support, and thus N*M evaluations (for N particles in the given KDE, which is resampled onto a grid of M points).

Comment: A simple procedure would be to compute the KDE of a nonlinear transform of the parameter and then convert it back.  Assuming anything close to a slowly-varying density near the origin, a good choice would be the $n^\text{th}$ root of the distance in $n$ dimensions.

Comment: @whuber can you expand a bit?  I don't see how a transform helps the computational costs.  Or is the idea that you reshape the parameter space, to mimic the effect of changing the kernel (/ bandwidth)?  Do you know any references/tutorials for this, offhand?

Comment: An appropriate transformation will place approximately the same numbers of data in each one of a regularly-spaced set of bins.  Some examples appear at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65866

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a bit late, but this package: [KDEpy](https://kdepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) implements a convolution based FFTKDE which is *much faster*, than the [Scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html#scipy.stats.gaussian_kde) implementations.

Although it has some limitations, especially, regarding your case, a fixed bin size, but maybe the speed up is enough?

(sorry, new here... can not comment)

Comment: R uses FFT by default https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/cbae812b2414df898e522ca6dd5266ad0fee2e3a/src/library/stats/R/density.R#L170

Answer (score 0):

In case you have coarse bins I would consider to use the method described in the following paper: [Efficient Estimation of Smooth Distributions From Coarsely Grouped Data](https://academic.oup.com/aje/article/182/2/138/94562).
In appendix 2 you will find a R code illustrating the method. It should be easy to translate in in Python. 
I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but I don't quite follow how my problem is analogous to "ungrouping", can you elaborate a little on the connection?

Comment: Hi I think I misunderstood your question then, sorry. I thought that the under-sampled set of your data resulted in coarser bins. Anyway, the approach in the paper I suggested, is more general and can be used also in the case you do not have coarse bins as in [Ill-posed problems with counts, the composite link
model and penalized likelihood](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1014.8355&rep=rep1&type=pdf)