# "Simple" boundary correction method in kernel density estimation

Tags: references, kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

I'm new to kernel density estimation and have a rough idea on boundary bias.  When correcting for boundaries, I tried to use boundary correction method as "simple" which is available in R. Once I compile,  I could find that the method works properly as the boundary error percentage decreases when this boundary correction method is applied.  I want to learn "what" it actually is this "simple" boundary correction.  What's the mechanism of it? The only source I found is given below:

[Simple boundary correction
for kernel density estimation](http://www.buch-kromann.dk/tine/nonpar/Simple%20boundary%20correction,%20Jones%201993.pdf)

I do not think this is exactly what I require. Could anyone kindly provide me any simply comprehensible source to understand the theory behind this? (a tutoring video would be better if available to understand how this correction works in example pictures)

Comment: [Look through this list](https://www.google.com/search?q=kernel+density+estimation+with+boundary&oq=kernel+density+estimation+with+boundary&aqs=chrome..69i57.20376j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: For alternative approaches see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65866.