# Estimation of the density at the bound of the support of a real random variable

Tags: estimation, extreme-value

Let $X$ be a random variable with real values and with density $f$.
Assume the support $f$ is bounded with supremum $m$ and has a positive value at that supremum:
$$\forall x > m, f(x) = 0 \text{  and  }  f(m)> 0.$$
Given an I.I.D. sample $X_1, \cdots, X_n$ of this random variable, I'd like to estimate both $m$ and $f(m)$.
What would be an good way to proceed ?

I think estimating $m$ by the sample maximum $\max(X_1, \cdots, X_n)$ yields a consistent estimator of $m$ with rate $\frac{1}{n}$, which satisfies me.

But I'm not sure on how to estimate $f(m)$. I tried to count the number of sample points falling in the interval
$$\left[ \max(X_1, \cdots, X_n) - \frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}, \max(X_1, \cdots, X_n) \right]$$
where $S$ is a consistent estimator of the standard deviation of $X$.
Hoping this would give a $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ consistent estimator of $f(m)$, but this seems to converge very slowly, and I don't think this is the best option.

Any input on that question would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you intend to distinguish between a case where the density falls rapidly to $0$ and one where it falls rapidly to a positive value, except with an enormous sample size?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understood your comment. You mean what if the slope of the density is very negative at $m$ ?

Comment: Does https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65866 answer your question?

Comment: @whuber : Thanks for the link to this nice question and dicussion. I guess I could use the proposed technique by replacing 0 by the maximum of the data. 
However, the cutting/ reweighting, while giving a good estimate of the density, has a bias at the edge, which is the value I'm interested in. 
For the logspline density estimation, I couldn't find any guarantee that the estimation is pointwise consistent (which would be what I need).
So I'm affraid this doesn't exactly answer my question.