On estimation of bivariate distribution
I am working with a non-negative, absolutely continuous bivariate random vector with the cumulative distribution function $F(x, y)$, and I am trying to estimate $$\int_0^{t_1}F^2(x_1,t_2)dx_1$$ using the Epanechnikov kernel,  $k(u)=\frac{3}{4}(1-u^2),|u|\leq1$ and its cdf is defined as $K(z)=\int_0^z k(u)du=\frac{1}{4}(3z-z^3)$. Estimation of this is defined as
$$\widehat{I}=\frac{1}{n^2h_1^2h_2^2}\int_0^{t_1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n K\left(\frac{x_1-X_{1i}}{h_1}\right)K\left(\frac{t_2-X_{2i}}{h_2}\right)\right)^2dx_1$$
Where $K(z)=\int_0^z k(x)dx$ is , $k$ is kernel.
For further details see here.
I am using the bivariate Gumbel distribution in my simulation. Below is my code, but I am having difficulty selecting an appropriate bandwidth for the bivariate data, and the estimated values I am getting are significantly different from the true values.
library(stats)
library(ks)
n <- 40
lambda1 = 2
lambda2 = 0.5
theta = 0.5

for (i in 1:100) {
  X1 <- rexp(n, lambda1)
term=1+lambda1*theta*X1
  X2 = rgamma(n, (runif(n) > 1 - theta/term)+ 1,(
lambda2*term)
  h1 <- 0.5
  h2 <- 0.55
  t1 <- 0.2
  t2 <- 0.3
 
  epan_kernel_cdf <- function(u) {
    0.25 * (3 * u - u^3)
  }
 
  integrals1 <- sapply(X1, function(Xi) h1 * epan_kernel_cdf((t1 - Xi) / h1))
  integrals2 <- sapply(X2, function(Yi) h2 * epan_kernel_cdf((t2 - Yi) / h2))
 
  integrand <- function(x1) {
    kernel_cdf_values <- sapply(X1, function(X1) epan_kernel_cdf((x1 - X1) / h1))
    prod_kernel <- kernel_cdf_values * integrals2
    sum_kernel <- sum(prod_kernel)
    (sum_kernel)^2
  }
 
  x_vals <- seq(0, t1, length.out = 10000)
  dx <- x_vals[2] - x_vals[1]
  sum_approx <- sum(sapply(x_vals, integrand)) * dx
  estimated_value <- (1/(n^2*h1^2*h2^2))*sum_approx
  true_value <- 0.98
 
  bias[i] <- estimated_value[1] - true_value
  MSE[i] <- mean((estimated_value[1] - true_value[1])^2)
}

bias
MSE
bias1 <- mean(bias)
bias1
MSE1 <- mean(MSE)
MSE1

Some specific issues I'm facing:

Choosing an appropriate bandwidth for my bivariate data.
My estimated values are far from the true value (0.98).

Any insights or suggestions on how to improve the bandwidth selection or other adjustments I should make in the code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Your question makes no sense, most likely due to typographical errors: the integrand of your integral doesn't depend on the variable of integration!

Ahhh sorry it is $dx_1$.

For such a distribution where the random variables only take non-negative values and where the marginal densities tend to be relatively large near zero values of the random variables, a fixed width kernel doesn't do so well (for example, giving positive densities at negative values of the random variables).  You might consider either taking logs of the random variables or use a reflection method.

Methods to carry out what @JimB recommends are given here on CV at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/65866.

The link you mention with the R code to generate x2 has been updated to fix a typo.  Also, your $\hat{I}$ seems to be using an estimate of $f(x_1,x_2)$  (the density) rather than the stated desire to use $F(x_1,x_2)$ (the cdf).  Giving an explicit formula fin the density or cdf in the text of the question would be helpful.

For the Epanechnikov cdf you'll need to account for values less than $-\sqrt{5}$ and greater than $\sqrt{5}$:  epan_kernel_cdf <- function(u) {if (u < -sqrt(5)) {0} else if (u > sqrt(5)) {1} else {(50 + 15*sqrt(5)*u - sqrt(5)*u^3)/100}}.

@JimB Thank you so much, I have edited.

I am unable to make much sense of the question as stated, because (1) $K$ is not a valid cdf and (2) the integral formula doesn't estimate a cdf even when $K$ is a cdf.

@wuber As I have taken non-negative random variables so limit starts from $0$.

Please have a look for further details https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X1201200313&ved=2ahUKEwjqm938xNSIAxUZoK8BHdFYIlAQFnoECAwQAQ&usg=AOvVaw1kt3E0mjw4_5KCVZ7-Vs9R.

Your question needs to be relatively self-contained (unless you happened to ask a question that some folks will be inspired to do the additional research).

@Unknown " I have taken non-negative random variables"  the $u$ that you put into your epan_kernel_cdf function can still be negative, because you are using difference expressions like $u = x_1-X_1$

An easy way to compute/estimate the integral instead is to create an empirical distribution function. That would at least be an easy rough method to verify the number true_value <- 0.98 that you are using. Also, plot your CDF as a contour plot, to see how it looks like. That would be an easy way to verify any potential mistakes.

The code doesn't execute because of several errors, like brackets and bias not being defined. (This is the difficulty with an interpreted programming language like R. While writing the code you might be depending on variables in your environment that are not created by that code, eg you can accidentally remove the lines, but the R session still remembers the variables)

If you have problems, then simplify and use plotting and intermediate evaluations to see what is going on.
Below is an example with a much simpler estimation method, namely the empirical CDF.
It indicates that the integral is around $\approx 5.5 \cdot 10^{-5}$

library(stats)
library(ks)
set.seed(1)
n = 10^5
lambda1 = 2
lambda2 = 0.5
theta = 0.5
t1 = 0.2
t2 = 0.3

x = rexp(n, lambda1)
term=1+lambda1*theta*x
y = rgamma(n, (runif(n) > 1 - theta/term)+ 1,(
lambda2*term))

### plot of the data
plot(x,y, pch = 21, cex = 0.3, col = rgb(0,0,0,0.1))
### the line along which we integrate the cdf
lines(c(0,t1),c(t2,t2), lwd = 2, lty = 2, col = 4)

### the cdf estimate to be integrated 
empiricalCDF = function(xi, yi=t2) {
   mean((x <= xi)*(y <= yi))
}
empiricalCDF = Vectorize(empiricalCDF)

dx = 0.001
xs = seq(0,t1,dx)
plot(xs, empiricalCDF(xs))
sum(empiricalCDF(xs)^2*dx) ## output is 5.510612e-05


In the example above I used 10^5 points. With only 40 points there are only a few values below (x= 0.3, y = 0.2). The empirical cdf (which is basically like the Epanechnikov kernel with zero bandwidth) will be very inaccurate, but also with larger bandwidth it doesn't help much. You need more data points to make a good estimate.
Here it is better to compute a single integral with the CDF based on 4000 points, instead of using the average of a hundred integrals with the CDFs based on 40 points.


Thank you so much for your answer, Currently I am outstation, I'll see soon.(+1)

This is just an extended comment saying that I think you need to give all of the information in the text for us to be able to determine the true answer.  I say that because given your links, I get 0.0000568597 as the true answer rather than 0.98.  Then we can deal with estimating that value with a kernel density estimator.
From your links the joint density appears to be
$$f(x_1,x_2)=\frac{(1-\theta ) \lambda_2 \lambda_1+\theta ^2 \lambda_2^2 \lambda_1^2 x_1 x_2+\theta  \lambda_2 \lambda_1^2 x_1+\theta  \lambda_2^2 \lambda_1 x_2}{\exp (\theta  \lambda_2 \lambda_1 x_1 x_2+\lambda_1 x_1+\lambda_2 x_2)}$$
The joint distribution function is then
$$F(x_1,x_2)=\exp (\lambda_2 (-x_2)-x_1 (\lambda_1+\theta  \lambda_2 \lambda_1 x_2))-e^{\lambda_1 (-x_1)}-e^{\lambda_2 (-x_2)}+1$$
Using your parameters ($\theta=1/2$, $\lambda_1=2$, $\lambda_2=1/2$, $t_1=1/5$, and $t_2=3/10$), I get
$$F(x_1,t_2)=e^{\frac{1}{20} (-43 x_1-3)}-e^{-2 x_1}+1-\frac{1}{e^{3/20}}$$
and
$$\int_0^{t_1} F(x_1,t_2)^2 dx_1= \int_0^{1/5} \left(e^{\frac{1}{20} (-43 x_1-3)}-e^{-2 x_1}+1-\frac{1}{e^{3/20}}\right)^2 dx_1$$
$$-\frac{11}{20}-\frac{1}{4 e^{4/5}}-\frac{107}{215 e^{3/10}}+\frac{18707}{17845 e^{3/20}}-\frac{1}{e^{11/20}}-\frac{10}{43 e^{29/25}}-\frac{40}{43 e^{29/50}}+\frac{40}{83 e^{49/50}}+\frac{40}{43 e^{73/100}}+\frac{1}{e^{2/5}}\approx 0.0000568597$$

In addition, even without all the difficult computations, we always have $$\int_0^{t_1} F(x,t_2)^2 , dx < \int_0^{t_1} 1 , dx = t_2$$ and the value 0.98 is clearly wrong.

@SextusEmpiricus That is a much smarter way to go.
